# How to make an address clickable (detectable) by iphone html like phone numbers?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, safari

How to make an address clickable (detectable) by iphone safari like phone numbers? For the addresses it doesnt work directly.. Maybe there is a html tag for it?

thanks

Comment: There is an <address> tag in HTML. Maybe that's what you should be using. Not sure if the phone browsers recognize it and makes it clickable, like it does with phone numbers.
[http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_address.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_address.asp)

Comment: The webview that displays it must be configured to do so.

Comment: the w3schools address tags don't work! thanks here is the solution:
[http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007894-SW1](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007894-SW1)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Mobile devices look for 'http://maps.google.com/maps?' in the URL to launch the google maps app.

```
<a href='http://maps.google.com/maps?q=New+York+city&hl=en&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=58.598104,135.263672&vpsrc=1&hnear=New+York&t=m&z=11'>View in google maps</a>
```

Comment: yes you are right after i wrote this question, i found out the website from apple developer program. here it is the general website:

[http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007894-SW1](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007894-SW1)

Comment: To follow up on this, interestingly (though perhaps not surprisingly) the page on the apple developer site linked in the comment above now directs you to use the `maps.apple.com` URL and syntax for doing this. The problem I would guess is that this only works on iOS6, whereas iOS 5 and lower should keep using the google pattern. Much less on android.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Microdata](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/microdata.html#vcard).